# retrieve selected variables from caret recursive feature elimination (rfe) results

Tags: r, r-caret, feature-selection, rfe

In my working project, I use rfe function from caret package to do recursive feature elimination. I use a toy example to illustrate my point.

```
library(mlbench)
library(caret)
data(PimaIndiansDiabetes)

rfFuncs$summary <- twoClassSummary
control <- rfeControl(functions=rfFuncs, method="cv", number=10)
results <- rfe(PimaIndiansDiabetes[,1:8], PimaIndiansDiabetes[,9], sizes=c(1:8), rfeControl=control, metric="ROC")
```

The optimal variable selected is based on those variables that give highest auroc in the process and can be retrieved by `results$optVariables`. 
However, what I want to do is use '1 standard error rule' to select less features (code below). The number of variables identified is 4.

```
# auc that is 1-se from the highest auc 
df.results = results$results %>% dplyr::mutate(ROCSE = ROCSD/sqrt(10-1))
idx = which.max(df.results$ROC)
ROC.1se = df.results$ROC[idx] - df.results$ROCSE[idx]

# plot ROC vs feature size
g = ggplot(df.results, aes(x=Variables, y=ROC)) + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=ROC-ROCSE, ymax=ROC+ROCSE), 
                  width=.2, alpha=0.4, linetype=1) +
    geom_line() + 
    geom_point()+
    scale_color_brewer(palette="Paired")+
    geom_hline(yintercept = ROC.1se)+
    labs(x ="Number of Variables", y = "AUROC")
print(g)
```

The number of variables I identified is 4. Now I need to know which four variables. I did below:

```
results$variables %>% filter(Variables==4) %>% distinct(var)
```

It shows me 5 variables!

Does anyone know how I can retrieve those variables? Basically it applies to get those variables for any number of variables selected.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Check out my answer below.  In the future be sure to tag R questions with the `r` tag to get more visibility.

Answer (score 4):

**One-line Answer**

If you know you want only the best 4 variables from the rfe resampling, this will give you what you are looking for.

```
results$optVariables[1:4]
# [1] "glucose"  "mass"     "age"      "pregnant"
```

**`dplyr` Answer**

```
# results$variables %>%
#    group_by(var) %>%
#    summarize(Overall = mean(Overall)) %>%
#    arrange(-Overall)
#
# A tibble: 8 x 2
#   var      Overall
#   <chr>      <dbl>
# 1 glucose    34.2 
# 2 mass       15.8 
# 3 age        12.7 
# 4 pregnant    7.92
# 5 pedigree    5.09
# 6 insulin     4.87
# 7 triceps     3.25
# 8 pressure    1.95
```

**Why your attempt gives more than 4 variables**

You are filtering 40 observations.  10 folds of the best 4 variables.  The best 4 variables is not always the same within each fold.  Hence, to get the best top 4 variables across the resamples you need to average their performance across the folds as the code above does.  Even simpler, the variables within `optVariables` are sorted in this order, so you can just grab the first 4 (as in my one-line answer).  The proof that this is the case takes a bit of digging into the source code (shown below).

**Details: Digging into the source code**

A good first thing to do with objects returned from functions like `rfe` is to try functions like `print`, `summary`, or `plot`.  Often custom methods will exist that will give you very helpful information.  For example...

```
# Run rfe with a random seed
# library(dplyr)
# library(mlbench)
# library(caret)
# data(PimaIndiansDiabetes)
# rfFuncs$summary <- twoClassSummary
# control <- rfeControl(functions=rfFuncs, method="cv", number=10)
# set.seed(1)
# results <- rfe(PimaIndiansDiabetes[,1:8], PimaIndiansDiabetes[,9], sizes=c(1:8), 
# rfeControl=control, metric="ROC")
# 
# The next two lines identical...
results
print(results)
# Recursive feature selection
#
# Outer resampling method: Cross-Validated (10 fold)
#
# Resampling performance over subset size:
#
# Variables    ROC  Sens   Spec   ROCSD  SensSD  SpecSD Selected
#          1 0.7250 0.870 0.4071 0.07300 0.07134 0.10322         
#          2 0.7842 0.840 0.5677 0.04690 0.04989 0.05177         
#          3 0.8004 0.824 0.5789 0.02823 0.04695 0.10456         
#          4 0.8139 0.842 0.6269 0.03210 0.03458 0.05727         
#          5 0.8164 0.844 0.5969 0.02850 0.02951 0.07288         
#          6 0.8263 0.836 0.6078 0.03310 0.03978 0.07959         
#          7 0.8314 0.844 0.5966 0.03075 0.04502 0.07232         
#          8 0.8316 0.860 0.6081 0.02359 0.04522 0.07316        *
#
# The top 5 variables (out of 8):
#    glucose, mass, age, pregnant, pedigree
```

Hmm, that gives 5 variables, but you said you wanted 4.  We can pretty quickly dig into the source code to explore how it is calculating and returning those 5 variables as the top 5 variables.

```
print(caret:::print.rfe)
#
# Only a snippet code shown below...
#    cat("The top ", min(top, x$bestSubset), " variables (out of ", 
#        x$bestSubset, "):\n   ", paste(x$optVariables[1:min(top, 
#            x$bestSubset)], collapse = ", "), "\n\n", sep = "")
```

So, basically it is pulling the top 5 variables directly from `results$optVariables`.  How is that getting populated?

```
# print(caret:::rfe.default)
#
# Snippet 1 of code...
#    bestVar <- rfeControl$functions$selectVar(selectedVars, 
    bestSubset)
#
# Snippet 2 of code...
#        bestSubset = bestSubset, fit = fit, optVariables = bestVar,
```

Ok, `optVariables` is getting populated by `rfeControl$functions$selectVar`.

```
print(rfeControl)
#
# Snippet of code...
# list(functions = if (is.null(functions)) caretFuncs else functions,
```

From above, we see that `caretFuncs$selectVar` is being used...

**Details: Source code that is populating `optVariables`**

```
print(caretFuncs$selectVar)
# function (y, size)
# {
#    finalImp <- ddply(y[, c("Overall", "var")], .(var), function(x) mean(x$Overall, 
#        na.rm = TRUE))
#    names(finalImp)[2] <- "Overall"
#    finalImp <- finalImp[order(finalImp$Overall, decreasing = TRUE), 
#        ]
#    as.character(finalImp$var[1:size])
# }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly the OP would like to use the "1 standard error rule" to select variables instead of caret's default "choose the maximum/minimum" value.

One way to use the "1 standard error rule" when using RFE in the caret package is to modify the functions argument in the rfeControl object. Because caret has in-built function for several models (lmFuncs, rfFuncs, treebagFuncs and nbFuncs) it is possible to modify these functions to automatically select the variables using the 1 standard error rule.

A oneSE function requires the number of folds as an argument. Because it is hard to pass this as an argument when calling oneSE inside the RFE statement it is necessary to define a function with num=10 hard coded into the function. It is necessary to change the '10' in the following if using a different number of cross validation resamples.

```
oneSE10 <- function (x, metric, maximize) 
{
    index <- 1:nrow(x)
    if (!maximize) {
        bestIndex <- which.min(x[, metric])
        perf <- x[bestIndex, metric] + (x[bestIndex, paste(metric, 
            "SD", sep = "")])/sqrt(10)
        candidates <- index[x[, metric] <= perf]
        bestIter <- min(candidates)
    }
    else {
        bestIndex <- which.max(x[, metric])
        perf <- x[bestIndex, metric] - (x[bestIndex, paste(metric, 
            "SD", sep = "")])/sqrt(10)
        candidates <- index[x[, metric] >= perf]
        bestIter <- min(candidates)
    }
    bestIter
}
```

Then assign the oneSE function into the RFE control functions needed for each type of model. For example, to use the "1 standard error rule" for a randomForest model would be done as follows:

```
rfFuncs$selectSize <- oneSE10
```