# How to select top n number of variables using RFE in r?

Tags: r, classification, r-caret, rfe

I am running `RFE` on a dataset with `63 variables` after some preprocessing incl. `OneHotEncoding`.

**Issue:** when I run `rfe` with `sizes = c(15)` then it results in **15** & **63** `Variable` results. As the accuracy for **63** vars is marginally higher so by default it selects **63** `Variable` results.

**Want:** instead of **63** get **top 15 variables** as the difference in results is marginal but computationally it will be less expensive.

After reading from below post I realized I can use `optVariables[1:15]`

[retrieve selected variables from caret recursive feature elimination (rfe) results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52950003/retrieve-selected-variables-from-caret-recursive-feature-elimination-rfe-resul)

**Doubt:** If I use `RFE_single_size$optVariables[1:15]` is it selecting `top 15 vars` from the set of **63** returned vars or **15** `Variables`?

```
control <- rfeControl(functions = rfFuncs, method = "cv", verbose = FALSE)

system.time(
  RFE_single_size <- rfe(x = train_both_sample,    #  selected_vars[, 1:44]
                 y = pull(Y_train), 
                 sizes = c(15),
                 rfeControl = control
                 )
)

RFE_single_size
```

**RFE Results**

```
Recursive feature selection

Outer resampling method: Cross-Validated (10 fold) 

Resampling performance over subset size:

 Variables Accuracy  Kappa AccuracySD KappaSD Selected
        15   0.9646 0.9293   0.007279 0.01451         
        63   0.9702 0.9404   0.006592 0.01315        *

The top 5 variables (out of 63):
   duration, age, campaign, euribor3m, nr.employed
```

I would like to change the selection from **63** to **15** `Variables` to make sure I am selecting **top 15** from set of **15** `Variables` returned.

**About Data:** Data is taken from open source **"Bank marketing Response"** classification problem.

**UPDATE:** Added github link for code(rmd) & data csv file: https://github.com/johnsnow09/RFE

```
str(train_both_sample)

'data.frame':   2884 obs. of  63 variables:
 $ age                          : num  31 45 33 47 30 43 23 42 43 37 ...
 $ job.admin.                   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ job.blue.collar              : num  1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ job.entrepreneur             : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ job.housemaid                : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ job.management               : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ job.retired                  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ job.self.employed            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ job.services                 : num  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ job.student                  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ job.technician               : num  0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ job.unemployed               : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ job.unknown                  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ marital.divorced             : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ marital.married              : num  1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ marital.single               : num  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ marital.unknown              : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ education.basic.4y           : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ education.basic.6y           : num  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ education.basic.9y           : num  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ education.high.school        : num  0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ education.illiterate         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ education.professional.course: num  0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ education.university.degree  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 ...
 $ education.unknown            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ default.no                   : num  1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 ...
 $ default.unknown              : num  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ default.yes                  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ housing.no                   : num  0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ housing.unknown              : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ housing.yes                  : num  1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 ...
 $ loan.no                      : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 ...
 $ loan.unknown                 : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ loan.yes                     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ contact.cellular             : num  0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 ...
 $ contact.telephone            : num  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 ...
 $ month.Mar                    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ month.Apr                    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ month.May                    : num  1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ month.Jun                    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ month.Jul                    : num  0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ month.Aug                    : num  0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ month.Sep                    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ month.Oct                    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ month.Nov                    : num  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ month.Dec                    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ day_of_week.fri              : num  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ day_of_week.mon              : num  0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ day_of_week.thu              : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 ...
 $ day_of_week.tue              : num  1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ day_of_week.wed              : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ duration                     : num  97 68 335 208 136 107 87 123 246 204 ...
 $ campaign                     : num  2 4 3 4 2 2 1 1 2 3 ...
 $ pdays                        : num  999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 ...
 $ previous                     : num  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ poutcome.failure             : num  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ poutcome.nonexistent         : num  1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ poutcome.success             : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ emp.var.rate                 : num  1.1 1.4 1.4 -1.8 1.4 -0.1 1.4 1.1 1.4 1.4 ...
 $ cons.price.idx               : num  94 93.9 93.4 92.9 93.9 ...
 $ cons.conf.idx                : num  -36.4 -42.7 -36.1 -46.2 -42.7 -42 -36.1 -36.4 -41.8 -42.7 ...
 $ euribor3m                    : num  4.86 4.96 4.97 1.3 4.96 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As I have not received any answer from SO post so I have attempted in two ways:

1. `RFE_single_size$optVariables[1:15]`

Then `vif` on these vars.

2. Selected all **22** Imp Variables for **15** `Variables` (22 vars is due 10 Folds that have differnt set of vars in each fold) and then have average it out.

[image]

```
rfe_selected_vars <- RFE_single_size$variables %>% 
  filter(Variables == 15) %>% 
  group_by(var) %>% 
  summarise(Overall = mean(Overall)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Overall)) %>% 
  pull(var) 

rfe_selected_vars

[1] "duration"                      "age"                           "campaign"                     
 [4] "euribor3m"                     "nr.employed"                   "cons.conf.idx"                
 [7] "cons.price.idx"                "housing.no"                    "housing.yes"                  
[10] "day_of_week.thu"               "job.admin."                    "marital.married"              
[13] "loan.no"                       "marital.single"                "job.technician"               
[16] "emp.var.rate"                  "day_of_week.mon"               "education.university.degree"  
[19] "education.high.school"         "day_of_week.tue"               "day_of_week.wed"              
[22] "education.professional.course"
```

then `vif` on these vars.

**Selected vars for formula:**

y ~ duration + age + campaign + nr.employed + cons.conf.idx +
cons.price.idx + housing.yes + day_of_week.thu + job.admin. + marital.married + loan.no +
job.technician + education.high.school + day_of_week.tue + day_of_week.wed +
education.professional.course

**Conclusion:**

Overall list of vars is little different in both cases but result from **MARS** is approx same with very marginally higher in **second case** for `train` data and didn't show any improvement on `test` data.